# WCF + Entity Framework design

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

I was wondering how to design this best..

On my ASP.NET MVC application I have a database and I want to use a WCF to handle all my interaction with that database through EF. So I've create a Entity Model on the service which I use to interact with the database. In order to interact with the WCF from the ASP.NET app I've created DTO's for each EF model (I only have 3) and a Converter class to convert from the EF models to the DTO's and vice versa.

On a side-note.. would it be possible to avoid using DTO's and just transfer the EF models instead? - I've tried, but with no luck as the client asp.net app doesnt recognize these models.

Is this a suitable way of designing this or would another approach be better?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This architecture is indeed used in situations where business logic and data access logic is deployed on another server then asp.net frontend. Reason for such architecture can be company policy, security, scalability, etc. But usually it is for bigger projects.

You said that you have 3 "EF models". Does it mean that you have 3 EDMXs files or 3 entities? If you mean 3 entities than your project is probably very small and unless you really must use this architecture (direct requirement) or unless you are doing just some test project there is no reason to do that.

How do you use DTOs? Is it just (or very close) 1:1 mapping to EF entity? In such case you missed DTOs purpose and you most probably don't need them. If your service exposes CRUD operations you can use EF entities directly (but you must use POCO or STE).

Moreover if you just want to expose EF model as CRUD service you should check [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).

Comment: What I have is a single EDMX with 3 entities which is created in the WCF service project. The DTO's I have are mapped 1:1 to the entities and therefor I guess they are not needed, but how do I go about using the entities instead?

Comment: What type of entities are you using? Entity objects or POCOs? What problems did you have when sending entities directly?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this:                                `DataLayerServiceClient dls = new DataLayerServiceClient();
PERSON p = new PERSON
{
  ID = 1,
  Fornavn = "hans",
  Efternavn = "hansen",
  Adresse = "vej nr. 3",
  Postnummer = "1234",
  Telefonnummer = "12345678",
  Email = "mig@mail.dk"
};

dls.GetCreatePerson(p);`    but the 'PERSON' type is not available on the client..

Comment: If your service reference is correctly generated it must be available. If it is not available you have some problem on server side and GetCreatePerson method will not be available on client as well.

Comment: Just chiming in to agree that WCF Data Services is probably a better approach than raw WCF if you want to send business objects over the wire, as opposed to messages.

Comment: I've fiddled around with a WCF Data Service now and I got it to work.. but this surely is not very secure as it means that everyone who can reach the IP can effectively access my database?

Comment: Hi again.. I've managed to get the original idea to work.. with WCF Service and Entities. Everything works just as I wanted it to!  THanks for all the help..  my solution was primarily in scrapping my work and starting a new WCF Service from scratch and also keep it in another solution than my asp.net mvc solution.. :)